# Curl error: 56 (RECV_ERROR) & The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have implemented all the Tags using Yoast plugin on my blog. Still Facebook Debugger is throwing back these errors

> **Inferred Property** The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> **Missing Properties** The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
>
> **Could Not Connect To Server** Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers.
>
> **Curl Error** Curl error: 56 (RECV_ERROR)

**But I have the following on the page:**

```
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Sleepyhead"/>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Sleepyhead the most luxurious mattress! Starting at just Rs 8,999/- Sleepyhead"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://mysleepyhead.com/blog/sleepyhead-the-most-luxurious-mattress-starting-at-just-rs-8999/"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="People on an average spend 33% of their lifetime in bed! Your bed is a place where you relax, recover, and recharge your batteries. Considering the impact sleep has on our overall health, you may already be thinking about investing in a top of the line mattress. While what defines “luxury” is obviou"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://mysleepyhead.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Cover.jpg"/>
  <meta property="og:image:url" content="https://mysleepyhead.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Cover.jpg"/>
  <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://mysleepyhead.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Cover.jpg"/>
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="930"/>
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="675"/>
```

[Blog Link](https://mysleepyhead.com/blog/sleepyhead-the-most-luxurious-mattress-starting-at-just-rs-8999/)

[Facebook Debug Link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmysleepyhead.com%2Fblog%2Fsleepyhead-the-most-luxurious-mattress-starting-at-just-rs-8999%2F)

Comment: looks like a server issue: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/curl-error-56-3/

Comment: Clearly, if Facebook can't connect to your site, they also cannot find your meta tags.